# slice(-1) vs slice(0,-1) with one element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array - let's call it `array`.

When it has one element e.g. `[1]`, `array.slice(-1)` returns `[1]`.

However, `array.slice(0,-1)` returns `[]`.

Why is this difference?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

- Case 1: negative index as single parameter (start):
  "A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-1) extracts the last element in the sequence."
- Case 2: negative index as second parameter (end):
  "The index of the first element to exclude from the returned array."

You can play around with different parameters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#try_it).

Comment: Ohh I read this but I think I just now got it. With splice(-1) and an array of one element, it's offset by one from the end of the array, which ends up circling back around to the element?

Comment: Yes, the last element is your only element.